# Generador de MACs, No puedo generar las Direcciones MAC que quiero

Tags: vb.net, macos, generador

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.TextBox1.Enabled = False
    Me.TextBox8.Enabled = False
    Me.TextBox9.Enabled = False
    Me.TextBox10.Enabled = False
    Me.TextBox11.Enabled = False
    Me.TextBox12.Enabled = False
    Me.TextBox15().Text = Conversions.ToString(200) ' En el form debería cambiar este valor y poner lo que quiero, pero no me deja, aunque ponga 200 solo generara 100 Macs.
    Me.count = 100 ' Solo genera de 100 en 100 al darle al botón generar.
End Sub
```

' Quiero que mi generador de Direcciones MAC, genere las macs que quiero, poniendo el numero de macs a generar en el textBox del formulario.

Comment: Faltan detalles en tu pregunta, por favor haz clic en [edit] y agrega lo que haga falta.

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 TL;DR: Con la cantidad de información en la pregunta, es imposible reproducir tu escenario, ergo, es muy poco probable dar una respuesta deseada. Edita la pregunta e incluye todo lo necesario para reproducir tu escenario. Saludos.